# Scaffold-DbContext throw ArgumentNullException

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first, ef-core-2.1

I get the following exception when I try to scaffold one of our databases.

```
For foreign key FK_ActivityEvent_ActivityCode on table dbo.ActivityEvent, unable to find the column called UniqActivityCode on the foreign key's principal table, dbo.ActivityCode. Skipping foreign key.
For foreign key FK_Line_Line on table dbo.Line, unable to find the column called UniqLine on the foreign key's principal table, dbo.Line. Skipping foreign key.
For foreign key FK_MarketingLine_MarketingLine on table dbo.MarketingLine, unable to find the column called UniqMarketingLine on the foreign key's principal table, dbo.MarketingLine. Skipping foreign key.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: column
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.GetPropertyName(DatabaseColumn column)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectListIterator`2.ToArray()
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitPrimaryKey(EntityTypeBuilder builder, DatabaseTable table)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitTable(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DatabaseTable table)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitTables(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, ICollection`1 tables)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitDatabaseModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DatabaseModel databaseModel)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(DatabaseModel databaseModel, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas, String namespace, String language, String contextDir, String contextName, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: column
```

I successfully scaffolded one of our databases so I'm sure I'm using the scaffold command properly. Also, I can access the database using the connection string I entered on the `Scaffold-DbContext` command.

I installed the following packages:

```
install-package microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver
install-package microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools
```

Using .NET Core Console App 2.1 on Windows 10.

Not sure if this is related but I get the following message when I try to expand the `Database Diagrams` in ssms. (I don't get this message on the other database that I successfully scaffolded)

[image]

Comment: You could consider creating the `DbContext` and model classes manually. I've had similar trouble once or twice using the scaffold command so I don't use it anymore. It's less work doing it by hand than trying to figure out what's wrong.